# CSH - check if variable is empty

Tags: unix, scripting, csh

Is there any more elegant way in checking if a variable is empty? Currently Im using:

```
if ( "x$mylist" == "x" ) then  #or even the ("$list" == "")
    echo "list is empty"
endif
```

I am already aware of the "pls dont CSH" here, but then I have no choice.

Comment: I don't think you need the `x` prefix trick; this seems to work: `if ($myList == "") then`. How is that inelegant? Are you also concerned that `$myList` might be unset (as opposed to set to the empty string)?

Comment: well my boss said its kind of inefficient and idk what he meant by that. tried this `if ($myList == "") then` and yep it worked also same way.

Comment: maybe he meant like the bash version in checking if a var is empty using the "-z" maybe he was thinking if i could apply it like that "efficient" way

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you can use `$?var` to determine whether `$var` is set. But that's not the same thing. If he thinks it's inefficient, surely he had a better idea. Ask.

Comment: yes, `if ( $?var ) then ` is your only hope, but efficiency is negligible, except for the pixels it takes to display this. See `http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-20` for the internet definitive version (search for `$?`) (or for old-school : http://www.amazon.com/The-Unix-Shell-Field-Guide/dp/013937468X/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1415160226&sr=8-7&keywords=csh+scripts) . Good luck.

Comment: apparently, `if ($myList == "") then` gives an if Expression:syntax error when triggered with some other valid parameters

Comment: but then `if ( "$mylist" == "" ) then` is working very ok. weird, thanks for the ideas anyway @Keith Thompson and @shellter

Comment: @shellter: `$?var` *doesn't mean the same thing*.